# Why does .append() not work on this list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append, jupyter-notebook

I have an object `scene` which is an instance of class `Scene` and has a list `children` which returns:

```
[<pythreejs.pythreejs.Mesh object at 0x000000002E836A90>, <pythreejs.pythreejs.SurfaceGrid object at 0x000000002DBF9F60>, <pythreejs.pythreejs.Mesh object at 0x000000002E8362E8>, <pythreejs.pythreejs.AmbientLight object at 0x000000002E8366D8>, <pythreejs.pythreejs.DirectionalLight object at 0x000000002E836630>]
```

If i want to update this list with a `point` which has type:

```
<class 'pythreejs.pythreejs.Mesh'>
```

I need to execute:

```
scene.children = list(scene.children) + [point]
```

Usually, I would execute:

```
scene.children.append(point)
```

However, while these two approaches both append `point`, only the first actually updates the list and produce the expected output (that is; voxels on a grid). Why?

The full code can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/voxelpainter).

Comment: No, `append` should work. If it doesn't, something very strange is going on and you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I understand, unfortunately i am having a bit of a problem producing a minimal example where this problem occurs :(... At the moment trying to figure out if i am doing something stupid which is causing this issue

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that `scene.children` is not actually a list, it is some other class which implements `append` but does not behave the way a list would. If you put `print(type(scene.children))` on the line immediately preceding `scene.children.append(point)`, what is the output?

Comment: @Kevin - that returns `<type 'list'>`; note that `scene` is and instance of class `Scene` and `children` is the list

Comment: How are you checking the contents of `scene.children` to see whether `point` is present inside it? Are you checking immediately after the `append` line, or sometime later?

Comment: How do you run that code?

Comment: @pacholik - its an ipython notebook file

Comment: @Kevin - as it turns out `point` is actually appended as `point in scene.children` returns `True` after appending. However, the result is that in the case `scene.children = list(scene.children) + [point]` the output is as expected (voxels are added to the grid) while the case `scene.children.append(point)` is not. This is really confusing :(...

Comment: Could be a reference sharing issue. If two variables exist that refer to the same list, then `append`ing to it will change the contents of the list of both variables. But if you do `scene.children = some_new_value`, then scene.children will point to a new list, and the other variable will still point to the old one.

Comment: Could it be that `scene.children` is a property that returns a copy of the list used internally? If you don't have the source or documentation, try `print(scene.children is scene.children)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this](https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/issues/26) issue, it turns out this is a `traitlets` issue. Modifying elements of `self.children` does not trigger an event notification unless a new list is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your issue is due to `children` being a `property` (or other descriptor) rather than a simple attribute of the `Scene` instance you're interacting with. You can get a list of the children, or assign a new list of children to the attribute, but the lists you're dealing with are not really how the class keeps track of its children internally. If you modify the list you get from `scene.children`, the modifications are not reflected in the class.

One way to test this would be to save the list from `scene.children` several times in different variables and see if they are all the same list or not. Try:

```
a = scene.children
b = scene.children
c = scene.children

print(id(a), id(b), id(c))
```

I suspect you'll get different `id`s for each list.

Here's a class that demonstrates the same issue you are seeing:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, values=()):
        self._values = list(values)

    @property
    def values(self):
        return list(self._values)

    @values.setter
    def values(self, new_values):
        self._values = list(new_values)
```

Each time you check the `values` property, you'll get a new (copied) list.

I don't think there's a fix that is fundamentally different than what you've found to work. You might streamline things a little by by using:

```
scene.children += [point]
```

Because of how the `+=` operator in Python works, this extends the list and then reassigns it back to `scene.children` (`a += b` is equivalent to `a = a.__iadd__(b)` if the `__iadd__` method exists).

Comment: The suggested print statement returns the same `id` for `a`, `b`, and `c`. Also, `scene.children+=[point]` does not produce the same result as `scene.children=list(scene.children)+[point]`. However, you are probably right that `scene.children` is not a simple list

Comment: Actually per the source code: https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/blob/master/pythreejs/pythreejs.py#L135, the author of the code apparently is having trouble getting a list of instances aswell: `TODO: figure out how to get a list of instances of Object3d`

Comment: Ah, well, perhaps it reuses the list object somehow. How exactly does the `+=` version behave? Does it not change anything in the `scene` object? Does skipping the `list` call in your code and just doing `scene.children = scene.children + [point]` work?

Comment: The `+=` like the `.append()` method both seem to add `point` to the list, however there is no voxel added to the scene when double clicked. Skipping the `list` call does work.